# STM32 nucleo Ethernet hard fault handler error

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

i am using STM 32 nucleo for our current project using Ethernet wiznet w5500 via SPI protocol.

Trying to get the waveform using oscilloscope but whenever i debug its going to hard fault error and i disabled other modules using SPI.

help me to rectify it.

thank you.

```
void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN HardFault_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END HardFault_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN W1_HardFault_IRQn 0 */
    /* USER CODE END W1_HardFault_IRQn 0 */
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe read some documentation?

Comment: I read but there is no update related ton this.

Comment: You need to show us the code that configures and uses the WizNet chip, not the hardfault handler. I've used this WizNet chip in an STM32 project and it works well. Can you set a breakpoint in the hardfault handler and look at the stack backtrace, it should tell you where it went wrong.

Comment: 1) show your code that actually hardfaults. You posted a function that literally does nothing at all. It's not very helpful. 2) Indicate after which line it hardfaults. If you don't feel comfortable with debugging tools, you can do while(1){blinkLED();} in your program right between your SPI commands or configurations. Move that blink caller around and see at what moment it hardfaults = doesn't reach blink code = hangs without blinking